# htmx three dependent selects immediate population of child elements on change

Tags: htmx

Consider this HTML page using the HTML Javascript package

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.8.0" integrity="sha384-cZuAZ+ZbwkNRnrKi05G/fjBX+azI9DNOkNYysZ0I/X5ZFgsmMiBXgDZof30F5ofc" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1>Prova</h1>

        <select name="brand" hx-get="/models" hx-target="#models" hx-trigger="change">
            <option value='325i'>325i</option>
            <option value='325ix'>325ix</option>
            <option value='X5'>X5</option>
        </select>

        <select name="model" id="models" hx-get="/models2" hx-target="#numbers" hx-trigger="change">

        </select>

        <select name="number" id="numbers">

        </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Consider that endpoints `models` and `models2` return a bunch of options depending on the value of the select being changed.
The response is something like:

```html
<option value='325i'>325i</option>
<option value='325ix'>325ix</option>
<option value='X5'>X5</option>
```

I wonder how I can make that whenever I change the select `brand`, that triggers the HTMX GET Request associated with the `model` select, which itself will populate the `numbers` select.

What I see happening, right now, is that the change to the `brand` dropdown triggers the population of the `model` dropdown.
I would expect the same to happen for the `number` dropdown as a consequence of the `model` dropdown value being changed but that is not happening. Can you elucidate me why that is not happening? And in that case how I can fix that using standard HTMX?

Comment: Can you provide more details. Is the request actually triggered on the second selector? The code itself looks fine imo.

Answer (score 2):

Swapping the new content into the `models` element does not actually trigger the `change` event on the `models` element. You'd need to define an additional trigger event to get the `models` element to issue its `hx-get` request when the `brand` changes and therefore the `models` options are updated. You could do this purely on the client side in HTMX with a delay so that your `models` selected value is sent. Or  you could have a combination of client custom trigger event and a HX-Response Header sent to the client to trigger that event.
Here is an example of a client event. Added a long 3 second delay to illustrate how the trigger from `brand` needs to wait until the swap has finished. If you just had the `from:brand` trigger without delay, it would fire instantaneously (before the `models` content was populated) so that post would not include the preselected `model` `option`. Essentially a race condition. Also went ahead and included the `brands` element in the `models2` request. Maybe you didn't want `models2` server side logic have to worry about the `brand`... but if two different `brands` had the same model name, then you may not know which set of `numbers` are supposed to be returned... For the following to work correctly, please add `id='brand'` to your `brand` `select` element.

```
<select name="model" id="models" hx-get="/models2" 
  hx-target="#numbers" hx-include="#brand" 
  hx-trigger="change, change from:#brand delay:3s">
</select>
```

The other way to do this would be to add a custom event into the `model` hx-trigger and then trigger that client event from the server in a Response Header. Added a short 5 millisecond delay so that HTMX has time to finish the swap before making the call to `models2` .. Again, so that the preselected `model` is included in the request to `models2`.

Clientside:

```
<select name="model" id="models" hx-get="?handler=models2" 
  hx-target="#numbers" hx-include="#brand" 
  hx-trigger="change, get-numbers from:body delay:5ms">
</select>
```

Server Side ASP.NET here (your server may need different syntax for adding Response Header)

```
Response.Headers.Add("HX-Trigger", "get-numbers");
```