# HTMX cascade load AND change

Tags: htmx

What I have working:

1. initial get/load for a Company select field
2. based on 1st selected default Company option, automatically load options for Building select
3. based on the 1st selected default Building option, automatically load a list of checkboxes

After everything is loaded:

- selecting a company will reload the buildings
- selecting a building will reload the rooms

However, selecting a company (which reloads the building), does not reload the rooms based on the default selected building.

I haven't seen any examples that reload cascading fields. I've seen this [htmx three dependent selects immediate population of child elements on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73103282/htmx-three-dependent-selects-immediate-population-of-child-elements-on-change), but it didn't address the issue.
Is this possible?

Here's my code:

```
Company 

<select 
    id="c" name="c" 
    hx-trigger="load" 
    hx-get="./get_companies.php"
></select> 

Building 

<select 
    id="b" name="b" 
    hx-get="./get_bldgs.php" 
    hx-trigger="load from:#c delay:250ms, change from:#c delay:250ms" 
    hx-include="#c"
></select>

Room

<span 
    id="r"
    hx-get="./get_rooms.php"
    hx-trigger="load from:#b delay:1s, change from:#b delay:1s"
    hx-include="#b"
></span>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Rooms` are listening to `load` and `change` events. When you select a `Company`, the `Building` is reloaded but at that point, neither `load` nor `change` event will be fired. See the JavaScript [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) about the `load`:

> The load event is fired when the whole page has loaded, including all dependent resources such as stylesheets, scripts, iframes, and images. This is in contrast to DOMContentLoaded, which is fired as soon as the page DOM has been loaded, without waiting for resources to finish loading.

That means the event filters on `Building` and `Room` (`load from:...`) are not doing anything, they only load once on initial page load.

To get the effect you are looking for, listen for `htmx:afterSettle` event from respective selects. You can restructure your code like so:

```
<!--Company-->
<select ... hx-trigger="load"...></select> 

<!--Company--> 
<select ...hx-trigger="htmx:afterSettle from:#c...">
</select>

<!--Room-->
<span ...hx-trigger="htmx:afterSettle from:#b..."></span>
```

The only thing to change is replacing `load` event with `htmx:afterSettle` on `Building` and `Room`. You can leave the rest as is (I only removed them to simply highlight the change).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was confusing the 2nd and 3rd loads with ajax get, and forgot they were for page loads.  It looks like things work well without the delays too which I'm glad to see.  But should I leave any delays in just in case?

Comment: If the only reason you had the delays was to ensure they only loaded AFTER the dependent select, then you can remove the delays. `afterSettle` is always fired at the the very end of request cycle. So you're assured that they will always run in succession. See the docs on the HTMX [order of request operations](https://htmx.org/docs/#request-operations).